# How to set the Nest Thermostat temperature with firebase?

Tags: firebase, nest-api

I'm using Firebase with the Nest API in Swift, but when I try to use setValue on a key in the Firebase structure, it tells me that it is read-only. I'm using the access token authorization, so I really don't know how to set thermostat temperatures. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you have read/write permissions in your Nest client? You may have only clicked the read permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, to set the temperature, you need to set `target_temperature_f` or `target_temperature_c`, instead of `target_temperature`.